# Aspose cells memory leak issue with version 17.2

Tags: excel, memory-leaks, aspose-cells

My goal to copy the excel data to SQL table by processing each cell (Need to have exactly same as excel data in SQL table).

Currently we are using Aspose Cells version 8.2.0.0. During performance testing memory leaks are reported.
So we are thinking to use 17.2.0.0 version Aspose Cells as it also supports explicit Dispose API on WorkBook Object.

To analyze memory leak issue, I explicitly called GC.Collect() after the processing is done by using both version Dlls. Live object count and memory is more or less same in both versions even after GC.Collect(). Please see the memory analysis as in attached.

[image: 8.2VersionMemoryAnalyzer]
[image: 17.2VersionMemoryAnalyzer]

My questions are :  Why still memory leak is there in new version of Aspose Cells as well?
Do we need to take any actions not to have leak in either of the versions? 
Please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have been improving and doing enhancements since many versions so we think, newest version should perform better.

We recommend you to perform the testing on most recent version which is at the moment 18.2.

Please note, here 18 means 2018 and 2 means February. Hence, the next official version will be 18.3 where 3 would mean March.

*Note: I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose*